# Pulsein() function blocks other tasks from running silmultaneously

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno, pulseaudio, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am using a zumo bot with a reflectance sensor used to follow a black line. I want to use an arduino to make the zumo bot stop once it gets a certain distance from an obstacle.

I have an ultrasonic sensor (HC-SR04) which ive connected to the bot.

Both of these tasks work independently but once i merge the code together(so it follows the line aswell as stoping when it detects an object using the ultrasonic sensor), it doesn't work properly.. (the zumo bot no longer follows the line)

I THINK it is to do with the pulsein() function blocking any other tasks but not sure.

My code is below. Can anyone help please?

````
#include <ZumoShield.h>

ZumoBuzzer buzzer;
ZumoReflectanceSensorArray reflectanceSensors;
ZumoMotors motors;
Pushbutton button(ZUMO_BUTTON);
int lastError = 0;

// This is the maximum speed the motors will be allowed to turn.
// (400 lets the motors go at top speed; decrease to impose a speed limit)
const int MAX_SPEED = 400;
#define echoPin A4 
#define trigPin A5

// defines variables
long duration; // variable for the duration of sound wave travel
int distance; // variable for the distance measurement

void setup()
{
  reflectanceSensors.init();

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an OUTPUT
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an INPUT

  // Initialize the reflectance sensors module

  // Wait for the user button to be pressed and released
  button.waitForButton();

  // Turn on LED to indicate we are in calibration mode
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

  // Wait 1 second and then begin automatic sensor calibration
  // by rotating in place to sweep the sensors over the line
  delay(1000);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 80; i++)
  {
    if ((i > 10 && i <= 30) || (i > 50 && i <= 70))
      motors.setSpeeds(-200, 200);
    else
      motors.setSpeeds(200, -200);
    reflectanceSensors.calibrate();

    // Since our counter runs to 80, the total delay will be
    // 80*20 = 1600 ms.
    delay(20);
  }
  motors.setSpeeds(0,0);

  // Turn off LED to indicate we are through with calibration
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);

  // Wait for the user button to be pressed and released
  button.waitForButton();


  Serial.begin(9600); // // Serial Communication is starting with 9600 of baudrate speed
  Serial.println("Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 Test"); // print some text in Serial Monitor
  Serial.println("with Arduino UNO R3");
  
  
}

void loop()
{

  unsigned int sensors[6];

  // Get the position of the line.  Note that we *must* provide the "sensors"
  // argument to readLine() here, even though we are not interested in the
  // individual sensor readings
  int position = reflectanceSensors.readLine(sensors);


  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin HIGH (ACTIVE) for 10 microseconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Our "error" is how far we are away from the center of the line, which
  // corresponds to position 2500.
  int error = position - 2500;

  // Get motor speed difference using proportional and derivative PID terms
  // (the integral term is generally not very useful for line following).
  // Here we are using a proportional constant of 1/4 and a derivative
  // constant of 6, which should work decently for many Zumo motor choices.

  int speedDifference = error / 4 + 6 * (error - lastError);

  lastError = error;

  // Get individual motor speeds.  The sign of speedDifference
  // determines if the robot turns left or right.
  int m1Speed = MAX_SPEED + speedDifference;
  int m2Speed = MAX_SPEED - speedDifference;


  if (m1Speed < 0)
    m1Speed = 0;
  if (m2Speed < 0)
    m2Speed = 0;
  if (m1Speed > MAX_SPEED)
    m1Speed = MAX_SPEED;
  if (m2Speed > MAX_SPEED)
    m2Speed = MAX_SPEED;

  motors.setSpeeds(m1Speed, m2Speed);

  //if (distance <20){
  //  motors.setSpeeds(0,0);
 // }
  

////////////////////////////////////////////


  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2; // Speed of sound wave divided by 2 (go and back)
  // Displays the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
  
}  ```
````

Comment: Yes, `pulseIn` blocks, as you can get from the reference. You can set a faster timeout, as the default allowed distance is a couple of meters far beyond your detection range. Or eventually avoid pulseIn

Answer (score 0):

Of course `pulseIn` is blocking function. Arduino project is open source, you can easily check [source code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c)
Here is C equivalent `countPulseASM` function which does measurement.

```
unsigned long pulseInSimpl(volatile uint8_t *port, uint8_t bit, uint8_t stateMask, unsigned long maxloops)

  {
      unsigned long width = 0;
      // wait for any previous pulse to end
      while ((*port & bit) == stateMask)
          if (--maxloops == 0)
              return 0;
 
      // wait for the pulse to start
      while ((*port & bit) != stateMask)
          if (--maxloops == 0)
              return 0;
 
      // wait for the pulse to stop
      while ((*port & bit) == stateMask) {
          if (++width == maxloops)
              return 0;
      }
      return width;
  }
```

If you need measure pulse length in non blocking way, use hw counters.